# устанавливаю zenmap на kali linux в итоге при вводе комнады "sudo gdebi zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb" выдает ошибку

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux

```
 sudo gdebi zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 86, in <module>
    if not debi.open(args[0]):
  File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 88, in open
    if not self._deb.check():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 565, in check
    if not self._satisfy_depends(self.depends):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 326, in depends
    apt_pkg.parse_depends(self._sections[key], False))
ValueError: Problem Parsing Dependency
```

Comment: Пробовали `sudo dkpg -i zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb`?

Comment: 1 ⨯
dpkg: предупреждение: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'zenmap':
 Поле «Depends», ссылка на «rpmlib»:
 неявная ссылка на номер версии, в таких случаях используйте «=»
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'zenmap':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'rpmlib': version 'PartialHardlinkSets': номер версии не начинается с цифры
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Устанавливаю файл deb именно zenmap\_7.91-1\_all.deb, выдаёт ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248529/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-deb-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-zenmap-7-91-1-all-deb-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: дополнил исходный вопрос тем, что написано в этом. @mepihindeveloper, смотрите исходный вопрос.