# Устанавливаю файл deb именно zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dpkg

[image: код который при команде]

```
$  sudo dpkg -i zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb                                1 ⨯
dpkg: предупреждение: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'zenmap':
 Поле «Depends», ссылка на «rpmlib»:
 неявная ссылка на номер версии, в таких случаях используйте «=»
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'zenmap':
 'Depends' field, reference to 'rpmlib': version 'PartialHardlinkSets': номер версии не начинается с цифры
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 zenmap_7.91-1_all.deb
```

---

Comment: Ошибка в control файле пакета, обратитесь к тому, кто этот пакет собирал. Только проверьте сперва, что этот пакет предполагается к использованию в вашей ОС (включая версию ОС) и почему не через репозиторий.

Comment: Пакет на официальном сайте zenmapa его в сути удалили в целом, zenmap из Kali Linux удалили

Comment: `sudo apt install nmap` ?